# Need to sync branch and tags between Github repo to Azure devops repo

Tags: github, azure-devops

I am moving from Github to Azure devops repo.
Now I already have a repo in Azure devops, but is old, and now I need to sync it from Github.

Maybe there is some branches that is not in Azure devops, also Tags.

I am using:

```
git branch -r | grep -v '\->' | while read remote; do git branch --track "${remote#origin/}" "$remote"; done
git push https://xxxx@dev.azure.com/_git/reponame -u --all --force
```

But I am not sure that this command move all branch to Azure devops.
Also I don't see new Tags that's been created **after** I imported the entire Github repo.

How do I also sync the tags?

Answer (score 1):

I needed to add this line and will transfer all tags to the new repo.

```
git push https://xxxx@dev.azure.com/_git/reponame -u --tags --force
```